How safely to make on filament / mysql site global search is case insensitive?
On laravel / filament / mysql site global search is case insensitive.
I can not edit eloquent queries like :
Model::whereRaw("UPPER('{$column}') LIKE '%'". strtoupper($value)."'%'");

as it is filament site.
Mysql was created with utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci and has data in english/spain/ukrainian.
In .emv file I set parameter :
DB_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci

and got error :
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8mb3_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET
'utf8mb4' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 1 limit 1)

I suppose that in php myadmin I need to create a new database with utf8_general_ci and upload dump of database onto hard disk
and upload the dump into new database  utf8_general_ci. Can it be that I could lose some of my data in english/spain/ukrainian ?
Are there some tools/app for such import ?
"laravel/framework": "^11.19",
"filament/filament": "^3.2-stable",
Mysql 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1

Thanks in advance!

You only need to convert data if you change characeter set. You can change collation without data conversion as long as the character set is the same. Btw ci at the end of a collation name indicates that it is case insensitive.

Also, in mysql when there are bith utf8 and utf8mb4 character sets, tjen use the latter (along with the right collation) as utf8 in mysql used onky 3 bytes to represent a character. This has now been rectified.
